# The type or namespace name 'UIFocusEventArgs' & 'LocalDate' could not be found in Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, nodatime

According to Nodatimepicker [documentation](https://github.com/nheath99/NodaTimePicker), I'm trying to add a Datepicker named [Nodatimepicker](https://github.com/nheath99/NodaTimePicker) in my Blazor Server side App.

```
void focussed(UIFocusEventArgs e)
{
    visible = true;
}
void selected(LocalDate localDate)
{
    visible = false;
    StateHasChanged();
}
```

But i'm faceing the following error.....

> The type or namespace name 'UIFocusEventArgs' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> The type or namespace name 'LocalDate' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Thanks In Advance...

Comment: So *do* you have `using` directives for those types? If you don't have `using NodaTime;` at the top of your file for example, that would definitely be a problem. If you don't want to add a `using` directive, you could always change the signature to `void selected(NodaTime.LocalDate localDate)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use FocusEventArgs instead of UIFocusEventArgs which is obsolete

Add the following using directive for the LocalDate:

```
using NodaTime;
using System;
```

Comment: Thanks, it's work but a another error arise in method Selected=@selected as "Cannot convert method group 'selected' to non-delegate type 'object'. Did you intend to invoke the method?"

Comment: @Osman Goni, sorry, but I'm not familiar with Nodatimepicker. Please, create a new question with the relevant code, and I'll try to help you..